# Which bottle will cool down faster?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, thermal-conductivity

I have two transparent bottles of nearly the same base diameter and cap diameter (Implying that both bottles have similar cap and base area respectively). But one is taller than the other by 15 cm.

The bottles are made of the same material (PolyPet) and I poured cold water at the same temperature to both of them and observed.

I found that :

1. If I opened the cap the temperature of water just around the cap was higher than that of water below it. The water below it had a comparably low temperature.Does that mean that waters acts as an insulator to prevent heat exchange (to some degree)?
2. The smaller bottle cooled down later while the taller one faster. I thought that the reverse would happen as it would be relatively easy to cool down a smaller quantity of liquid than a larger one. But the opposite happened.

I could not find any reasons for the above. I repeated the above steps thrice getting the same results.

Comment: Need a bit more detail. Are these bottles transparent? What is the temperature of the surroundings? Is there any (sun) light or other source of heat? What is causing "cold" water to cool (further)? Are you putting these bottles in a fridge? If so - are they standing on an actively cooled surface?

Comment: You made several edits but still didn't answer my question: what is the mechanism for cooling your cold water? Also - what is your metric for "cool faster" (other than sticking a finger in the bottle)? Do you have an objective method for measuring temperature? Note - interesting things happen when water cools below 4 C (it starts to expand...). We need to know more about your setup to give you a proper answer.

Comment: I used a standard mercury thermometer and mechanism is cooling through basically sun rays.I kept them outside and checked.

Comment: Wouldn't the water heat up if you put it in the sun?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59184/discussion-between-floris-and-classikalmechanik).

Comment: -1. This is a very confusing question.

Comment: @sammygerbil What confusion do you have ?

Comment: @ClassiKalMechanik We don't know how you set all of this up or measured temperatures.  It's not "normal" behaviour, so we can't really assume your setup is heating them evenly; and there may be something in the setup that explains why the second part of your question happens.

Comment: Let me check that!

Comment: Confusing: you still mix "heating" and "cooling". Among other things.

Comment: My confusion is the same as repeated by Floris : your title asks about "heating up" but your experiment talks about cold water being cooled (with no mention of freezing) by the sun's rays (cooling by evaporation?). ... Also, there is no mention of temperature readings, so we have no idea of the size of the effect.

Comment: Wait... what _is_ the intention of this question?  Based on your comments in chat, these bottles are being heated.  Yesterday you changed the title to say "heated" instead of "cooled"; but as mentioned here, most of the question still talked about cooling.  You edited the title again this morning to "cooled"; which is the opposite of what you said yesterday.  We really can't help you if you don't even seem sure what your setup was or what you were doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ideal conditions, here are some thoughts:

1) Warmer water is less dense than cooler water, so it follows that the warmer water will tend to move toward the top of the bottle.

2) The surface area of the taller bottle is greater, so rate of heat transfer out of it is greater than the rate of heat transfer of the smaller bottle. Perhaps the specifications of the bottles are such that this discrepency in rate of heat transfer outweighs the difference in mass that is cooled.

Comment: the surface area to volume ratio is greater for the small bottle though. Heat is roughly proportional to mass which is proportional to volume. If the law of cooling applies. Then the rate of cooling should be directly proportional to this ratio and the temperature gradient as a function of time. I think the experiment should be further questioned before we try to explain the second point

Comment: @rpfphysics If the difference in the height of the bottles is primarily due to an elongation of the bottle's neck, there will be greater surface area per unit volume. I tested this with the simplified scenario of two stacked cylinders of different radii, then seeing that the ratio of surface area to volume increases when the height of the cylinder with the smaller radius is increased.

Comment: @Ziggurat The question says "... nearly the same base diameter and cap diameter...But one is taller than the other by 15 cm".  This implies that we should assume they are the same size if we assume anything.

Comment: @JMac That's what I assumed; the radii remained the same, and the height changed.

Answer (score 1):

Changing from heating to cooling does change the situation somewhat.

Depending on how you allowed them to heat, you could definitely say that the heating "insulated" the bottom of the bottle (if being heated from above).

When you heat water, the lower density water moves up (heating lowers the density).  This creates [natural convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_convection).  This process assists the heat transfer by circulating the water.

Heating from the top creates stagnation.  The warm water is already on top, so it will not circulate.  The water transfers it's heat the same way a solid object would, by [conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction) (which is much less effective, it's like not stirring vs. stirring).

The tall one heating up faster seems odd.  That may have had to do with orientation though.  Without more information on your setup and conditions we would only be guessing why that occurs.

Comment: Could  you please explain how hot water stagnates ?

Comment: I did.  Lower density waters moves up.  Heating lowers the density.  Heating from the top means there's nowhere "up" for the less dense water to move.